# Getting null pointer when calling web serive developed in the .net using web service client

Tags: java, web-services, websphere

I am consuming a web service developed in the .net.
My platform is IBM RAD,WebSphere 7 and jax rpc.

I write the codeto call the service, getting below null pointer exception.
Client code:

```
     // String
      // endPoint="https://pilot.id3global.com/ID3gWS/ID3global.svc/Soap11_NoAuth";

      // String endPoint="BasicHttpBinding_GlobalAuthenticateStub";
      // GlobalAuthentication globalAuth =new GlobalAuthentication();

      Long l = new Long("0");
      // globalAuth.setProfileID("4a6eaf41-f9a9-44f0-9700-81aa43004dab");
      // globalAuth.setProfileVersion(l);

      GlobalProfileIDVersion profileIDVersion = new GlobalProfileIDVersion();

      profileIDVersion.setID("4a6eaf41-f9a9-44f0-9700-81aa43004dab");
      profileIDVersion.setVersion(l);

      GlobalInputData iInputData = new GlobalInputData();

      GlobalPersonal personal = new GlobalPersonal();
      GlobalPersonalDetails personalDetails = new GlobalPersonalDetails();
      personalDetails.setForename("Raymond");

      personalDetails.setSurname("Smith");
      personalDetails.setDOBDay(01);
      personalDetails.setDOBMonth(11);
      personalDetails.setDOBYear(1951);
      personalDetails.setGender(GlobalGender.Male);

      personal.setPersonalDetails(personalDetails);

      GlobalAddresses globalAddress = new GlobalAddresses();
      GlobalAddress globalAdres = new GlobalAddress();
      globalAdres.setPremise("3");
      // iInputData.Addresses.CurrentAddress.Building = "";
      // THis is commented out as I am just sending through a Building Number in
      // Premise whereas this is used for Building Names
      // iInputData.Addresses.CurrentAddress.SubBuilding = "";
      // This is commented out as no Flat/Apartment is being sent
      globalAdres.setStreet("High Street");
      globalAdres.setCity("Westbury");
      globalAdres.setZipPostcode("BA13 3BN");
      globalAdres.setCountry("United Kingdom");
      globalAddress.setCurrentAddress(globalAdres);
      GlobalIdentityDocuments identityDocuments = new GlobalIdentityDocuments();
      GlobalInternationalPassport internationalPassport = new GlobalInternationalPassport();
      internationalPassport
            .setNumber("1234567897GBR4511012M1803035<<<<<<<<<<<<<<00");
      internationalPassport.setExpiryDay(03);
      internationalPassport.setExpiryMonth(03);
      internationalPassport.setExpiryYear(2018);
      internationalPassport.setCountryOfOrigin("United Kingdom");

      identityDocuments.setInternationalPassport(internationalPassport);

      // BasicHttpBinding_GlobalAuthenticateStub stub=new
      // BasicHttpBinding_GlobalAuthenticateStub("https://pilot.id3global.com/ID3gWS/ID3global.svc/Soap11_NoAuth","dfasdf");
      // IGlobalAuthenticate authenticate=proxy.getIGlobalAuthenticate();

      URL wsdlLocationURL = new URL(
            "https://pilot.id3global.com/ID3gWS/ID3global.svc?wsdl");
//      URL wsdlLocationURL = new URL("WEB-INF/wsdl/ID3global.wsdl");
      // QName qname = new QName("http://www.id3global.com/ID3gWS/2013/04",
      // "AuthenticateSP");
      // Final===> QName qname = new
      // QName("http://www.id3global.com/ID3gWS/2013/04", "ID3global");
      QName qname = new QName("http://www.id3global.com/ID3gWS/2013/04",
            "ID3global");

      Service service = Service.create(wsdlLocationURL, qname);
      QName portQName = new QName("http://www.id3global.com/ID3gWS/2013/04",
            "basicHttpBinding_GlobalAuthenticate");
      IGlobalAuthenticate proxy = service.getPort(portQName,
            IGlobalAuthenticate.class);

      /******************* UserName & Password ******************************/
      Map<String, Object> req_ctx = ((BindingProvider) proxy)
            .getRequestContext();
//      req_ctx.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
//            "https://pilot.id3global.com/ID3gWS/ID3global.svc?wsdl");

      Map<String, List<String>> headers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
      headers.put("Username", Collections.singletonList("nreddy"));
      headers.put("Password", Collections.singletonList("password"));
      req_ctx.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, headers);

      iInputData
            .setAddressDocuments(new GlobalAddressDocuments());
      iInputData.setAddresses(new GlobalAddresses());
      iInputData
            .setBankingDetails(new GlobalBankingDetails());
      iInputData
            .setContactDetails(new GlobalContactDetails());
      iInputData.setEmployment(new GlobalEmployment());
      iInputData.setGlobalGeneric(new GlobalGeneric());
      iInputData.setIdentityDocuments(identityDocuments);
      iInputData.setImages(new GlobalImage[1]);
      iInputData.setLocation(new GlobalLocation());
      iInputData.setPersonal(personal);
      // GlobalResultData response = null;
      try
      {
         GlobalResultData response = proxy.authenticateSP(profileIDVersion,
               "Example12345", iInputData);

         // System.out.println("out responce after the proxycall"+response.getBandText().toString());

      }
      catch ( RemoteException e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      return "";
```

Excepetion:

```
[28/1/16 11:21:37:584 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: java.lang.NullPointerException
[28/1/16 11:21:37:584 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.createWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:175)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:585 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:70)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:585 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory.makeWebServiceException(ExceptionFactory.java:128)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:585 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.runtime.description.marshal.impl.MarshalServiceRuntimeDescriptionBuilder.init(MarshalServiceRuntimeDescriptionBuilder.java:79)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:585 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.runtime.description.marshal.impl.MarshalServiceRuntimeDescriptionBuilder.create(MarshalServiceRuntimeDescriptionBuilder.java:52)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:585 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.runtime.description.marshal.MarshalServiceRuntimeDescriptionFactory.get(MarshalServiceRuntimeDescriptionFactory.java:53)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:586 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.factory.MethodMarshallerFactory.getMarshaller(MethodMarshallerFactory.java:111)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:586 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createRequest(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:458)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:586 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:241)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:586 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:208)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:586 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy27.authenticateSP(Unknown Source)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:586 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.eeft.ws.ppd.AuthenticateWSBeanPortBindingImpl.callRequest(AuthenticateWSBeanPortBindingImpl.java:283)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:587 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.eeft.ws.ppd.AuthenticateWSBeanPortBindingImpl.authenticate(AuthenticateWSBeanPortBindingImpl.java:73)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:587 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:587 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:588 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:588 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:589 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.java.JavaDispatcher.invokeMethod(JavaDispatcher.java:203)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:589 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.java.JavaDispatcher.invokeOperation(JavaDispatcher.java:158)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:589 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.SoapRPCProcessor.processRequestResponse(SoapRPCProcessor.java:490)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:589 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.SoapRPCProcessor.processMessage(SoapRPCProcessor.java:433)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:589 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.BasicDispatcher.processMessage(BasicDispatcher.java:134)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:589 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.dispatchers.java.SessionDispatcher.invoke(SessionDispatcher.java:204)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:589 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:263)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:590 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.jaxrpc.JAXRPCHandler.invoke(JAXRPCHandler.java:153)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:590 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.handlers.WrappedHandler.invoke(WrappedHandler.java:64)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:590 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:263)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:590 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.PivotHandlerWrapper.invoke(PivotHandlerWrapper.java:263)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:592 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.WebServicesEngine.invoke(WebServicesEngine.java:336)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:592 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServlet.doPost(WebServicesServlet.java:1246)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:592 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:592 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.transport.http.WebServicesServletBase.service(WebServicesServletBase.java:344)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:592 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:593 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1700)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:593 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:970)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:593 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:508)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:593 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:593 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3994)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:593 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:593 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:594 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:595 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:595 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:454)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:595 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:516)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:595 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:307)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:596 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:278)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:596 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:596 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:596 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:596 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:597 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:597 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:597 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:597 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:597 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:598 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1662)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:598 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[28/1/16 11:21:37:599 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.runtime.description.marshal.impl.ArtifactProcessor.getPackageName(ArtifactProcessor.java:497)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:599 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.runtime.description.marshal.impl.ArtifactProcessor.build(ArtifactProcessor.java:107)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:599 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.runtime.description.marshal.impl.MarshalServiceRuntimeDescriptionBuilder.init(MarshalServiceRuntimeDescriptionBuilder.java:77)
[28/1/16 11:21:37:599 EET] 00000023 SystemErr     R     ... 52 more
```

I am completely stuck with this and any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Naren

Comment: The answer to your query is here already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Not a helpful comment. The NPE is in (to the OP) a third-party webservice library.

Answer (score 0):

You may create the wrong service.

First you must create service:

```
final Constructor<S> serviceConstructor = serviceClass.getConstructor(URL.class, QName.class);
serviceConstructor.newInstance(**null**, new QName(SERVICES_NAMESPACE, serviceName));
```

And put param with end-point:

```
String endpointAddress = “http://.....”;
            ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, endpointAddress);
            LOG.trace("Endpoint address is \"{}\".", endpointAddress);
```